# weka algorithm to place ambulances based on historical accident data

Tags: java, algorithm, gps, weka, k-means

I am trying to develop a system for hospital and I need to recommend best location to place ambulances. I'll have historical accidents data.

I should be able to achieve these things.

1. Identify best locations to place ambulances
2. Based on number of accidents I should be able to recommend multiple ambulances for one area also.
3. I should be able to suggest optimum number of ambulances

Sample data as follows

---

```
Incident date   incident type   Landmark    Distance from landmark
***********************************************************************
1-1-2017    Vehicle crash   Shop A      1 KM
1-2-2017    Vehicle crash   Shop A      2 KM
1-2-2017    Vehicle crash   Shop A      1 KM
1-3-2017    Vehicle crash   Shop A      3 KM
1-3-2017    Vehicle crash   Shop A      1 KM

1-1-2017    Vehicle crash   Shop B      1 KM
1-2-2017    Vehicle crash   Shop B      2 KM
1-2-2017    Vehicle crash   Shop B      1 KM

1-1-2017    Vehicle crash   Shop C      1 KM
1-2-2017    Vehicle crash   Shop C      2 KM
1-2-2017    Vehicle crash   Shop D      1 KM
```

Assuming Shop A and Shop B are far away but Shop C and Shop D are near.
As per above sample data I should be able to recommend below results

```
Shop A - 2 Vehicles
Shop B - 1 Vehicle
Shop C & D (Together) - 1 Vehicle
```

I am trying to implement logic in java using Weka library.

I tried with K-Means algorithm but I am forced to give number of clusters nothing but number of available vehicles in my case.

But I want algorithm should be able to identify best number of vehicles. I think EM may be better suitable in my case but in density based evaluation I'm always getting zero clusters.

Any help or guidance is appreciated

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show what you have tried up to now